# Error connect remote with database when create subscription in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I don't understand the error I'm getting. I have a virtual machine with Windows Server 2012 and Win 10. I installed SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on it.

Now, when I set distributed database, I set publication with my win 10. After I set publication success and I set subscription in publication, set success but when I watch virtual machine not result. And error not connect with virtual machine.

[Here is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oomt5.png)

Please help me !

Comment: Can you elaborate? As a side note, i'm surprised you used an Enterprise license on a virtual machine...

Comment: i finded but not result to my error..... Why you surprise about that??. :D.

Comment: Well you stated you put windows 10 on it not a Server OS so it makes me think it's a test environment  and Enterprise is pretty pricey....

Comment: i run virtual machine with Window server 2012. :D. and my OS is win 10